# Не работают Typesafe Activator команды в Centos

Tags: centos, playframework

У меня VPS с CentOs, установил Typesafe Activator, при наборе любых команд активатор, после некоторого ожидания, командная строка выдает "убито", java установлено, не могу понять в чем дело, помогите, пожалуйста!)

Comment: *при наборе любых команд активатор, после некоторого ожидания, командная строка выдает "убито"* — непонятно, **где** вы всё это набираете, и где видите надпись «убито» (надеюсь, что это не шутка).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, не хватает оперативной памяти. Попробуйте подключиться через ещё одно ssh-соединение и набрать:

```
free -m -s 1.
```

Будет показываться количество свободной памяти и в этот момент надо запустить ту команду, которая выдаёт "killed". Думаю, в этот момент будет показано, что свободная память стремиться к нулю, а, после убийства процесса, резко взлетит. Помогает переход на Xen (т.к. OpenVZ не поддерживает swap, насколько я знаю).